# Cannot connect to IPSEC/L2TP VPN Arch Linux/Windows 8

Tags: vpn, ipsec, openswan, xl2tpd

I have check a lot of other L2TP/IPsec VPN post and none of them seem to quite match the issues I am having so here is what going on.

I am trying to set up a VPN on my Arch Linux server that I can connect to from my local devices (most of which are running Windows 8.1). For the whole post, I am going to use the fake external IPs of 123.1.1.1 and ff:ff:ff:ff for the Arch serverand 123.2.2.2 as the IP for the Windows 8.1 desktop I am trying to connect from.

I have everything set up and running following [this config setup](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_on_a_Raspberry_Pi_with_Arch_Linux.html). Ports 1701 TCP, 4500 UDP and 500 UDP are open properly on the Arch server and it is not an ARM server, but rather a 64-bit server. When I try to connect from the Windows 8 device, I get the following error:

```
Error 789: The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security error encountered a processing error during the initial negotions with the remote computer.
```

**ipsec auto --status** (after I try to connect)

```
000 using kernel interface: netkey
000 interface lo/lo ::1
000 interface eth0/eth0 ff:ff:ff:ff::1
000 interface eth0/eth0 123.1.1.1
000 interface eth0/eth0 123.1.1.1
000 %myid = (none)
000 debug none
000
000 virtual_private (%priv):
000 - allowed 5 subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, fd00::/8, fe80::/10
000 - disallowed 0 subnets:
000 WARNING: Disallowed subnets in virtual_private= is empty. If you have
000          private address space in internal use, it should be excluded!
000
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=2, name=ESP_DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=64, keysizemax=64
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=3, name=ESP_3DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=192, keysizemax=192
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=6, name=ESP_CAST, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=7, name=ESP_BLOWFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=448
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=11, name=ESP_NULL, ivlen=0, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=12, name=ESP_AES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=13, name=ESP_AES_CTR, ivlen=8, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=14, name=ESP_AES_CCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=15, name=ESP_AES_CCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=16, name=ESP_AES_CCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=18, name=ESP_AES_GCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=19, name=ESP_AES_GCM_B, ivlen=12, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=20, name=ESP_AES_GCM_C, ivlen=16, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=22, name=ESP_CAMELLIA, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=252, name=ESP_SERPENT, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=253, name=ESP_TWOFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=1, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_MD5, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=2, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA1, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=5, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_256, keysizemin=256, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=6, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_384, keysizemin=384, keysizemax=384
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=7, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_512, keysizemin=512, keysizemax=512
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=8, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_RIPEMD, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=9, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_AES_CBC, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=251, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_NULL_KAME, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=0, name=(null), blocksize=16, keydeflen=131
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=5, name=OAKLEY_3DES_CBC, blocksize=8, keydeflen=192
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=7, name=OAKLEY_AES_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=1, name=OAKLEY_MD5, hashsize=16
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=2, name=OAKLEY_SHA1, hashsize=20
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=4, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_256, hashsize=32
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=6, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_512, hashsize=64
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=2, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=5, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1536, bits=1536
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=14, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=15, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP3072, bits=3072
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=16, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP4096, bits=4096
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=17, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP6144, bits=6144
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=18, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP8192, bits=8192
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=22, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=23, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH23, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=24, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH24, bits=2048
000
000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,0,0} trans={0,0,0} attrs={0,0,0}
000
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT": 123.1.1.1<123.1.1.1>:17/1701...%any:17/%any; unrouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT":     myip=unset; hisip=unset;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT":   ike_life: 28800s; ipsec_life: 3600s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 3
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT":   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+PFS+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 32,32; interface: eth0;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT":   dpd: action:clear; delay:10; timeout:20;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]: 123.1.1.1<123.1.1.1>:17/1701...123.2.2.2[10.0.0.231]:17/1701; unrouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:     myip=unset; hisip=unset;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:   ike_life: 28800s; ipsec_life: 3600s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 3
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+PFS+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 32,32; interface: eth0;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:   dpd: action:clear; delay:10; timeout:20;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:   newest ISAKMP SA: #1; newest IPsec SA: #0;
000 "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2]:   IKE algorithm newest: AES_CBC_256-SHA1-MODP2048
000
000 #2: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2] 123.2.2.2:55371 STATE_QUICK_R0 (expecting QI1); EVENT_CRYPTO_FAILED in 286s; nodpd; idle; import:not set
000 #1: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[2] 123.2.2.2:55371 STATE_MAIN_R3 (sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 28516s; newest ISAKMP; nodpd; idle; import:not set
000
```

**ipsec verify**

```
Checking if IPsec got installed and started correctly:

Version check and ipsec on-path                         [OK]
Openswan U2.6.41/K3.14.12-1-lts (netkey)
See `ipsec --copyright' for copyright information.
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                    [OK]
 NETKEY: Testing XFRM related proc values
         ICMP default/send_redirects                    [OK]
         ICMP default/accept_redirects                  [OK]
         XFRM larval drop                               [OK]
Hardware random device check                            [N/A]
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding    [OK]
Checking rp_filter                                      [ENABLED]
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter                 [ENABLED]
Checking that pluto is running                          [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                     [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on tcp 500                     [NOT IMPLEMENTED]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on udp 4500              [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on tcp 4500              [NOT IMPLEMENTED]
 Pluto listening for IKE on tcp 10000 (cisco)           [OK]
Checking NAT and MASQUERADEing                          [TEST INCOMPLETE]
Checking 'ip' command                                   [OK]
Checking 'iptables' command                             [OK]

ipsec verify: encountered errors
```

**Configs:**

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
version 2
config setup
    dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
    nat_traversal=yes    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
    protostack=netkey
    plutoopts="--interface=eth0"
    force_keepalive=yes
    keep_alive=60

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
    authby=secret
    pfs=yes
    auto=add
    keyingtries=3
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    type=transport
    left=123.1.1.1
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    right=%any
    rightprotoport=17/%any
    dpddelay=10
    dpdtimeout=20
    dpdaction=clear
```

**/etc/ipsec.secrets** (values changed to bogus stuff for security reason, but the pre-shared keys has been verifed on the client)

```
: RSA   {
        # RSA 2192 bits   mydomain.net   Thu Jul 17 09:16:05 2014
        # for signatures only, UNSAFE FOR ENCRYPTION
        #pubkey=0xf1f1f1
        Modulus: 0xf1f1f1
        PublicExponent: 0x03
        # everything after this point is secret
        PrivateExponent: 0xf1f1f1
        Prime1: 0xf1f1f1
        Prime2: 0xf1f1f1
        Exponent1: 0xf1f1f1
        Exponent2: 0xf1f1f1
        Coefficient: 0xf1f1f1
        }
# do not change the indenting of that "}"

123.1.1.1  %any:   PSK "somereallylongstring"
```

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

```
[global]
ipsec saref = yes
saref refinfo = 30

[lns default]
ip range = 172.16.1.30-172.16.1.100
local ip = 172.16.1.1
unix authentication = yes
require authentication = yes
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

**/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd**

```
login
ms-dns 208.67.222.222
ms-dns 208.67.220.220
auth
mtu 1200
mru 1000
crtscts
hide-password
modem
name l2tpd
proxyarp
lcp-echo-interval 30
lcp-echo-failure 4
```

**/etc/ppp/pap-secrets**

```
# Secrets for authentication using PAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
*       l2tpd           ""              *
```

**/etc/pam.d/ppp**

```
auth    required        pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_unix.so
account required        pam_unix.so
session required        pam_unix.so
```